# Returning a reference local variable assigned by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I'm being a bit confused about this simple case:

```
O& foo() { 
  O& o = bar(); // sig: O& bar();
  return o; 
}
```

Is that ok ? I'm quite confident it is, but I searched advanced explanations about this, and nothing definitive popped up. Any good reference ? Or maybe am I just wrong ?

EDIT: the result from the bar() function is legit (it's a reference element from a list), and making the o variable static is not really part of the question, I just wanted to make sure a local variable assigned by reference can itself by returned by reference. static's semantic is entirely different.

Comment: You are saying that `bar()` is returning a reference to an element of a list. So your answer is "Yes" if the list and its elements exist after `return`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't returning a reference to a local variable. The following code returns a reference to a local variable:

```
 O& foo() {
     O o;
     return o;
 }
```

In your code, 'o' is already a reference. It's not a variable assigned by reference, it *is* a reference.

The fact that the function also returns a reference simply means that you pass the reference back, not a reference to your reference. Simply put: your function simply returns a reference. Lets flesh it out:

```
struct O {};
static O s_o;

O& foo() { return s_o; } // returns a reference, to s_o

O& bar() {
    O& o = foo(); // os now refers to s_o;
    return o; // o is a reference, but it refers to s_o,
    // so this returns a reference to s_o, not o.
    // we're returning "O&", not "(O&)&".
}
```

This is essentially the same as the following:

```
O* bar(); // returns a pointer to X.
O* optr = bar(); // optr points to X.
return optr; // returns the address of x.
```

We're not returning a pointer to 'optr' here, we're returning the value that optr contains, which is a pointer to an instance of an 'O'.

In C++ references are generally implemented as a contractual layer over pointers - that is, the underlying type of a reference is generally a pointer. The contract trades access to the pointer, thus the ability to change what the reference points/refers to, in exchange for some degree of guarantee that it will refer/point to a concrete instance. There are ways you can still shoot yourself in the foot with a reference, especially when referencing the target of a pointer.

The simplest reduction of your code then, which from the callers perspective has the same effect:

```
O& foo() {
    return bar();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what `bar` returns. If it returns a local variable by reference, then no. If the returned value is persistent after it returns, the yes.

```
O& bar() {
   static O o;
   return o;
}

O& bar1() { 
   return O();  // temporary
}

O& foo() { 
  O& o = bar();   // okay
  O& o1 = bar1(); // not okay
  return o; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I validated kfsone's, because of it was more extensive, but yours was fast and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `static` keyword to let your object exist after being returned from. But this way you are not following rules of object orientation.
If you are returning the reference to avoid cost of copying, you can use `shared_ptr<O>` by which you will return the address of `o` and you will not worry about deleting your pointer or such issues.
[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) you can find how shared_ptr works.

Answer (score -1):

You can make `static` object to return local variables for a single threaded application:

```
O& foo() { 
  static O o = bar();
  return o; //foo will return reference to O
}
```

For Multi threading : This will work in c++11

Comment: @Bathsheba but static varibles would initialized only once

Comment: OK, that will work now: now you've dropped the reference type on the static. If you point out the pitfalls then you'll be sure to attract upvotes.